# Daylight to Standard timezone conversion in iOS

Tags: ios, timezone, dst, date-conversion

Some countries are observing daylight saving, but I want to get the timezone name irrespective of daylight saving.

In short I want standard time of such countries instead of daylight saving time.

Is there any way to convert this or anything else?

P.S. I want this because of my server requirement.

//----------------------------------------------------------------

I have seen this reference in apple.

```
+ (instancetype)timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(NSInteger)seconds
```

> Discussion The name of the new time zone is GMT +/– the offset, in
>   hours and minutes. Time zones created with this method never have
>   daylight savings, and the offset is constant no matter the date.

But I wonder how it will useful to me for my problem? As I want timezone name without daylight saving not any time with offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually this

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
   NSTimeZoneNameStyleStandard,
   NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortStandard,
   NSTimeZoneNameStyleDaylightSaving,
   NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortDaylightSaving,
   NSTimeZoneNameStyleGeneric,
   NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortGeneric 
} NSTimeZoneNameStyle;
```

The enum answered it for me. My bad , I should have read this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the time zone with respect to GMT **without** accounting for DST, the simplest option would be to:

1. Find the DST offset using 'daylightSavingTimeOffset' on your suspect time zone.
2. Subtract that value from the timezone's GMT offset.
3. Create a new time zone with the now adjusted offset.

If you need the *name* of the standard time zone, the simplest approach might just be to look for "DST" and "Daylight" in the time zone description and then pick the time zone that has the greatest number of words matching to the DST time zone. That might not be the most elegant solution, but it would work for most time zones.